# WWW_PATH variable in PHP

Tags: php, apache, directory, document-root

I have a file in my project: `/include/prepend.inc.php` which gets `require`d at the start of each file. In it, I have a line like this:

```
define( 'PATH', dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

It works great - it defines `PATH` as the server's document root, so for other stuff, no matter what file included how many levels deep, I can just use:

```
require PATH . '/include/something_else.inc.php`.
```

However I now want the same thing, but for browsers. If `PATH` is the document root of the server, `WWW_PATH` should contain the empty string. If the project is stored in a `/something/` directory in the document root, `WWW_PATH` should contain `/something`.

The idea is that I can do this:

```
<script src="<?=WWW_PATH?>/js/foo.js"></script>
```

At the moment I just do:

```
<script src="/js/foo.js"></script>
```

and it breaks if the project is stored in a subdirectory.

I don't want to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` since it is unreliable and doesn't work on most shared hosts.

Any ideas?

Comment: did u try to use `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
```

AND OR

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

OR

```
define('SOMETHING', PATH . '/js');
```

AND THEN

```
<script src="<?php echo SOMETHING; ?>/foo.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should work at least semi-decently, if you're not doing too much URL rewriting (ie: if your URLs map straightforwardly to filenames).  At least on Linux, which uses `/` to separate directory names, making it possible to use `dirname` with URLs.  Not sure how well it'll work on Windows.

Comment: Yeah the thing is `PATH . '/js/foo.js'` (as your code effectively does) is useless to the browser - `PATH` contains the *filesystem* path, such as `/var/www`, and a browser would choke on this. I'll look at $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME`].

Comment: is your project going to be in one place, if so why not `define('ROOT', 'http://localhost');` ?

Comment: @Connor: A decently developed project will never be in just one place.  At the very least, there'll also be a development/test server, so it's easier to change stuff with less worry about accidentally breaking the live site.

Comment: Nope, neither `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` (contains, eg, 'localhost') nor `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (contains, eg, 'foo.php') is what I'm after.

Comment: @Connor that's definitely not an option because it's an open source project designed to be used on others' servers

Comment: @DuncanNZ: Odd... `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should contain the url from the root of the site down to the script.  That's what it's there for.  For `http://localhost/whatever/file.php`, it should contain `/whatever/file.php`.  That, plus the server name, should be enough to build a full URL.

Comment: @cHao yep but I don't want a full URL. I want to compare `PATH` against the document root of the server, essentially.

Comment: @DuncanNZ: Thing is, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` looks a whole lot like a filename -- so you can easily use `dirname` with it, just like you do with `__FILE__`.

Comment: well, with both of them you can get the full URL, you cant get any better than the full URL